# Why using the symbol "$" in Angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

[image]

Based on the picture with the white selection.

I don't understand why you need to use the symbol "$". (https://www.twilio.com/blog/prevent-memory-leaks-angular-observable-ngondestroy)

What is the purpose to use a symbol "$"?
What benefit is it to use it?

Thank you!

Comment: Its just a convention to denote the RxJS streams (subjects, observables etc.). Read more about it in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables).

Comment: It's not mandatory, just a convention for naming observables.

Comment: It's not mandatory. Just a best-practices convention to refer observables, subjects, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit for the same reason that async methods in C# often have the `Async` suffix,it's a convention that helps you understand when you read the code that there is something special with this property.

The goal is just to make clear that this parameter is a stream and should not be used as-is but, for example, should be awaited.